# ¿Cómo puedo validar una expReg (solo Texto) y marcar checkboxs en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo la siguiente aplicación en JavaScript, necesito saber como validar esta expresión correctamente y marcar los checkbox 3 máximos.

El resultado final sería este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a) Un campo usuario en el que utilizaremos expresiones regulares para comprobar que contiene al menos un guión bajo, una mayúscula, y una minúscula.

b) Dos campos para introducir una contraseña y comprobaremos que son iguales.

c) 5 campos de tipo check de los cuales podemos elegir 3 como máximo.

d) En caso de que alguna de las validaciones falle, mostramos el mensaje de error en la parte inferior del formulario, marcamos el cuadro en rojo y ponemos el foco en ese campo.

Tengo el siguiente código, lo único que no me funciona es los checkbox y la ExpReg

```js
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.id = "mainForm";

    var labelNombre = document.createElement("label");
    labelNombre.setAttribute("for", "usuario");
    labelNombre.innerHTML = "Usuario : ";

    var inputUsuario = document.createElement("input");
    inputUsuario.setAttribute("type", "text");
    inputUsuario.setAttribute("name", "usuario");
    inputUsuario.id = "user";

    var labelPass = document.createElement("label");
    labelPass.setAttribute("for", "password");
    labelPass.innerHTML = "Contraseña :";

    var inputPass = document.createElement("input");
    inputPass.setAttribute("type", "password");
    inputPass.setAttribute("name", "pass");
    inputPass.id = "password";

    var labelPass2 = document.createElement("label");
    labelPass2.setAttribute("for","password2");
    labelPass2.innerHTML = "Repita Contraseña :";
    
    var inputPass2 = document.createElement("input");
    inputPass2.setAttribute("type", "password");
    inputPass2.id = "password2";

    var checkbox1 = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox1.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox1.className = "check";

    var Labelcheckbox1 = document.createElement("label");
    Labelcheckbox1.setAttribute("for", "futbol");
    Labelcheckbox1.innerHTML = "Fútbol";

    var checkbox2 = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox2.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox2.className = "check";

    var Labelcheckbox2 = document.createElement("label");
    Labelcheckbox2.setAttribute("for", "baloncesto");
    Labelcheckbox2.innerHTML = "Baloncesto";

    var checkbox3 = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox3.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox3.className = "check";

    var Labelcheckbox3 = document.createElement("label");
    Labelcheckbox3.setAttribute("for", "ciclismo");
    Labelcheckbox3.innerHTML = "Ciclismo";

    var checkbox4 = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox4.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox4.className = "check";

    var Labelcheckbox4 = document.createElement("label");
    Labelcheckbox4.setAttribute("for", "Esqui");
    Labelcheckbox4.innerHTML = "Esqui";

    var checkbox5 = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox5.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox5.className = "check";

    var Labelcheckbox5 = document.createElement("label");
    Labelcheckbox5.setAttribute("for", "Balonmano");
    Labelcheckbox5.innerHTML = "Balonmano";

    var botonValidar = document.createElement("button");
    botonValidar.setAttribute("type", "button");
    botonValidar.innerHTML = "Validar";

    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(labelNombre);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(inputUsuario);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(labelPass);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(inputPass);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(labelPass2);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(inputPass2);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(Labelcheckbox1);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(checkbox1);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(Labelcheckbox2);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(checkbox2);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(Labelcheckbox3);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(checkbox3);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(Labelcheckbox4);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(checkbox4);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(Labelcheckbox5);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(checkbox5);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(botonValidar);

    mainForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
         e.preventDefault();
         const filter = (nodes, callback) => {
             if (typeof callback === "function") {
                 const result = [];
                 nodes.forEach((el, i) => {
                     if (callback(el, i)) {
                         result.push(el);
                     }
                 });
                 return result;
             } else {
                 return [];
             }
         }
         const r = /(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?:\d|([a-zA-Z-_])(?!.*\1))*/;
         const isValid = r.test(user.value) && password.value === password2.value && (filter(mainForm.querySelectorAll(".check"), e => {
             return e.checked;
         }).length <= 3 && filter(mainForm.querySelectorAll(".check"), e => {
             return e.checked;
         }).length !== 0);
         console.log(isValid ? "Válido" : "No válido");
     });
```

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes validar que contenga el guion bajo, junto con minúsculas y mayúsculas con la siguiente expresión

```regex
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?:\d|([a-zA-Z-_])(?!.*\1))*
```

```js
const r = /(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?:\d|([a-zA-Z-_])(?!.*\1))*/;

console.log(r.test("_"));
console.log(r.test("_a"));
console.log(r.test("A_a"));
console.log(r.test("_AAAAAAAa"));
```

Para los checkboxes bastaría usar [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Pondremos todos los checkboxes con una sola clase y usaremos [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) en el `<form>` para obtener todos los elementos con la clase

```js
NodeList.prototype.filter = function(callback) {
  if (typeof callback === "function") {
    const result = [];
    this.forEach((el, i) => {
      if (callback(el, i)) {
        result.push(el);
      }
    });
    return result;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}

mainForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const isValid = (mainForm.querySelectorAll(".check").filter(e => e.checked).length <= 3 && mainForm.querySelectorAll(".check").filter(e => e.checked).length !== 0);
  console.log(isValid ? "Válido" : "No válido");
});
```

```html
<form id="mainForm">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

En este caso, un *NodeList* (lo que nos da `querySelectorAll` no tiene un método nativo de `filter`), por lo que crearemos uno

Recorreremos cada elemento del *NodeList* ejecutando el *callback* y si devuelve `true`, vamos a añadir el elemento actual a `result` y finalmente lo devolvemos

En

```
isValid ? "Válido" : "No válido"
```

Usaremos un operador ternario, es un operador condicional de una sola línea el cual usaremos por su rapidez

```
condición ? cuando es true : cuando es false
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Y finalmente, para validar que los dos campos tengan el mismo valor, podremos comparar la propiedad `value`

```
input1.value === input2.value
```

---

**Código final**

```js
mainForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const filter = (nodes, callback) => {
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
      const result = [];
      nodes.forEach((el,i) => {
        if (callback(el, i)) {
          result.push(el);
        }
      });
      return result;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
  const r = /(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?:\d|([a-zA-Z-_])(?!.*\1))*/;
  const isValid = r.test(user.value) && password.value === password2.value && (filter(mainForm.querySelectorAll(".check"), e => {
    return e.checked;
  }).length <= 3 && filter(mainForm.querySelectorAll(".check"), e => {
    return e.checked;
  }).length !== 0);
  console.log(isValid ? "Válido" : "No válido");
});
```

```html
<form id="mainForm">
  <input id="user" />
  <input id="password" type="password" />
  <input id="password2" type="password" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

```js
var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.id = "mainForm";

    var labelNombre = document.createElement("label");
    labelNombre.setAttribute("for", "usuario");
    labelNombre.innerHTML = "Usuario : ";

    var inputUsuario = document.createElement("input");
    inputUsuario.setAttribute("type", "text");
    inputUsuario.setAttribute("name", "usuario");
    inputUsuario.id = "user";

    var labelPass = document.createElement("label");
    labelPass.setAttribute("for", "password");
    labelPass.innerHTML = "Contraseña :";

    var inputPass = document.createElement("input");
    inputPass.setAttribute("type", "password");
    inputPass.setAttribute("name", "pass");
    inputPass.id = "password";

    var labelPass2 = document.createElement("label");
    labelPass2.setAttribute("for","password2");
    labelPass2.innerHTML = "Repita Contraseña :";
    
    var inputPass2 = document.createElement("input");
    inputPass2.setAttribute("type", "password");
    inputPass2.id = "password2";

    var checkbox1 = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox1.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox1.className = "check";

    var Labelcheckbox1 = document.createElement("label");
    Labelcheckbox1.setAttribute("for", "futbol");
    Labelcheckbox1.innerHTML = "Fútbol";

    var checkbox2 = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox2.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox2.className = "check";

    var Labelcheckbox2 = document.createElement("label");
    Labelcheckbox2.setAttribute("for", "baloncesto");
    Labelcheckbox2.innerHTML = "Baloncesto";

    var checkbox3 = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox3.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox3.className = "check";

    var Labelcheckbox3 = document.createElement("label");
    Labelcheckbox3.setAttribute("for", "ciclismo");
    Labelcheckbox3.innerHTML = "Ciclismo";

    var checkbox4 = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox4.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox4.className = "check";

    var Labelcheckbox4 = document.createElement("label");
    Labelcheckbox4.setAttribute("for", "Esqui");
    Labelcheckbox4.innerHTML = "Esqui";

    var checkbox5 = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox5.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox5.className = "check";

    var Labelcheckbox5 = document.createElement("label");
    Labelcheckbox5.setAttribute("for", "Balonmano");
    Labelcheckbox5.innerHTML = "Balonmano";

    var botonValidar = document.createElement("button");
    botonValidar.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    botonValidar.innerHTML = "Validar";
    
    var errorMsg = document.createElement("div");
    errorMsg.setAttribute("id", "errMsg");

    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(labelNombre);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(inputUsuario);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(labelPass);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(inputPass);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(labelPass2);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(inputPass2);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(Labelcheckbox1);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(checkbox1);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(Labelcheckbox2);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(checkbox2);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(Labelcheckbox3);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(checkbox3);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(Labelcheckbox4);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(checkbox4);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(Labelcheckbox5);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(checkbox5);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(botonValidar);
    document.body.appendChild(form).appendChild(errorMsg);

    mainForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
         e.preventDefault();
         const filter = (nodes, callback) => {
             if (typeof callback === "function") {
                 const result = [];
                 nodes.forEach((el, i) => {
                     if (callback(el, i)) {
                         result.push(el);
                     }
                 });
                 return result;
             } else {
                 return [];
             }
         }
         const r = /(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?:\d|([a-zA-Z-_])(?!.*\1))*/;
         const isValid = r.test(user.value) && password.value === password2.value && (filter(mainForm.querySelectorAll(".check"), e => {
             return e.checked;
         }).length <= 3 && filter(mainForm.querySelectorAll(".check"), e => {
             return e.checked;
         }).length !== 0);
         if (isValid) {
          mainForm.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(el => {
            if (el === errorMsg) return;
            el.style.display = "none";
          });
          errMsg.innerHTML = "Los campos son correctos";
         } else {
          errMsg.innerHTML = "Los campos no son válidos";
          setTimeout(() => {
            errMsg.innerHTML = "";
          }, 1000);
         }
     });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta @anythingg , estaba buscado algo así para adaptarlo, buen código y limpio !

Comment: Una cosa curiosa que estoy probándolo con DOM pero no llega a funcionar, por que podría ser @anythingg ?

Comment: @DavidMilanes ¿Te sale algún error en la consola?

Comment: ni si quiera en consola te pego el código

Comment: @DavidMilanes ¿Podrías añadir el código HTML que empleas?

Comment: He realizado la misma estructura, pero aun así no marca nada en consola

Comment: Si arriba esta editado, Gracias !

Comment: me gustaría que salieran también si pueden ser los mensajes de error como se indica, es para tener una guía correcta de lo que se indica, gracias de nuevo !

Comment: @DavidMilanes Veo algunos errores, actualizaré mi respuesta en unos momentos

Comment: Gracias ! es de gran ayuda, puesto que es una guia para un examen que tengo próximo mas bien el dia 4 un saludo !

Comment: @DavidMilanes Este era tu error: el botón debería ser _type submit_ ya que al ser _type button_ el form no lo va a considerar como el botón de _submit_

Comment: ha joer que errores mas tontos cometo, gracias por la aclaración !

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120273/discussion-between-david-milanes-and-anythingg).

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta, muy detallada! Yo hubiera generado un arreglo desde la lista de nodos con [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) para aplicar el filtro, pero tu propuesta es muy interesante.